# How to use selectedIndexedChanged event in dropdown?

Tags: asp.net

In list of dropdown i have added some text and i want that if i select any particular text then it fired selectedIndexedChanged  event but its not firing.please tell me how it will fire  using C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `autopostback=true` declared in your page declaration?